# Iptables, правила, перенаправляющие на интерфейс eth1 все пакеты, приходящие на интерфейс eth0.

Tags: iptables

Добрый день, подскажите, пожалуйста, как Iptables написать правила, перенаправляющие на интерфейс eth1 все пакеты, приходящие на интерфейс eth0?

Пробовала пару вариантов, но все пакеты не перенаправляются.

Заранее спасибо)

Comment: Сформулируй свою целевую задачу, чую не правильно решение ты выбрал.

Comment: в бридж оба интерфейса собрать ?

Comment: Задача именно такая, т.к. мне обязательно нужно пользоваться iptables...

Comment: @Ice_Fox в смысле вы пытаетесь сделать неподходящим инструментом  зеркало интерфейса ? или вы хотите просто dnat/snat ? Уточните какие именно пакеты вы хотите перенаправлять ? iptables не работает с arp пакетами, для этого есть arptables.

Comment: Вы неправильно дали ТЗ.С такого ТЗ можно много чего подумать, даже на бондинг снестись.Опишите подробно задачу, чтоб было понятно, что вам надо получить и как Вы видите работу своей задачи...

Answer (score 1):

Могу ошибаться!

```
 # echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward  # iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE  # iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT  # iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
```